# How to assign variables in one py file and use them in other py files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python and I've got a problem working with variables.

I have `functions.py` file which contains a lot of functions and variables that I need to use in some other `.py` files. like this:

**functions.py:**

```
plc_variables = {}
plc_variables_path = ".../plc_variables.txt"

def get_plc_variables():
    global plc_variables
    plc_variables = some calculations which results a dictionary
```

**main.py**

```
import time
from functions import *

while True:
    get_plc_variables()
    print(plc_variables)
    time.sleep(1)
```

All I get is `{}`.
I want to call the `get_plc_variables()` to update `plc_variables` variable in a thread which contains a loop like this and use it in some other python files.
How can I do that?

Comment: In `get_plc_variables()` you assign a local variable that shadows the global `plc_variables` variable. So defining `plc_variables` to global is neccessary.

Comment: Although that is not a preferred way to share a common data between objects. Especially, if you work in multithreaded env. You should create a data object that is passed to the threads, or you can just update the variable directly. 
Not to mention, that you should solve the problem in a thread safe way, e.g., with a lock, etc.

Comment: @czeni I need the variable to be updated all the time, because it's being used in some other files and threads. If I have to call the whenever I want the last updated value, then I'd be calling it at least a hundred time per second, that's what I'm trying to avoid. do you have any suggestions for that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to return variable from function and assign it to some new variable, for example:

**functions.py**

```
plc_variables = {}
plc_variables_path = ".../plc_variables.txt"

def get_plc_variables():
    #global plc_variables
    plc_variables = some calculations which results a dictionary
    return plc_variables
```

**main.py**

```
import time
from functions import *

while True:
    plc_variable = get_plc_variables()
    print(plc_variables)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: This is totally unrelated to my problem, I don't wanna call `get_plc_varibales()` whenever I need the `plc_variables`, read the last 2 lines of the question again please.

Comment: it's the only way to do that, it's how python works. You can use global variables but it's a very bad practice. 

If you change variables do it inside some functions or classes, and then return new value.

Comment: if I do that, I'd be calling the function more than a hundred times per second, this is why I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: If you need to change some variable a hundred time per second it's ok to call a function a hundred time per second because calling a function it's a very quick operation. If your calculations are very easy do it directly in main.py and do not create separate python module functions.py for it.

Comment: =)) I know that, this is a very large program and the calculations that result the `plc_variables` are very complicated (more than 200 line of code with a lotta regular expressions and etc.), plus the program needs to use hardware resources as little as possible

Comment: So separate functions that's it for you. And it's required to return a new calculated value. And if there more than 200 lines of code in one function, maybe you need to think about refactoring.